# Jenkins SonarQube Standalone step fails with Unrecognized option: -e

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to use latest SonarQube Jenkins plugin (2.2.1) with older Sonar Runner (2.0). In [SONARJNKNS-212](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJNKNS-212) and [SONARJNKNS-214](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJNKNS-214) is introduced new parameter `-e` which is mandatory, used no matter of sonar runner version or wether user wants to. This parameter does not work with all Sonar runner versions, for example 2.0:

```
[vagrant@slave02 ~]# /jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/Sonar_Runner/bin/sonar-runner -e

Unrecognized option: -e

usage: sonar-runner [options]

Options:
 -h,--help             Display help information
 -X,--debug            Produce execution debug output
 -D,--define <arg>     Define property
```

`-e` should be configurable or reflect support of this parameter in used version of Sonar Runner

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are not using latest versions of the SonarQube Runner? SQ Runner 2.4 covers at least SQ 3.7+ (which is a wide compatibility).

Comment: Part of infrastructure is out of my control, and team which owns Sonar server do not plan upgrade in next few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

The "-e" option is recognized by SonarQube Runner 2.4 which is compatible with at least SQ 3.7 LTS - and therefore with 4.5 LTS. Version 2.0 of the runner is old and considered as obsolete.

If the SQ Jenkins plugin was successfully upgraded to 2.2.1, then it is also very easy to just update the settings of the Jenkins plugin to configure the SQ Runner to be 2.4 instead of 2.0. Like described in the [online documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Configuring+SonarQube+Jenkins+Plugin#ConfiguringSonarQubeJenkinsPlugin-AddingSonarQubeRunner), thanks to the automatic update, this can be done very smoothly.